# AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'name', however I'm calling a function within a class(?)

Tags: python, string

Here is the whole program. I'm not sure why but the error says this but I am using a seperate .py program to test all the functions within this class and I ran into this error that I can't seem to find a solution to.

> `File "C:\Python\PythonLab\PythonLab.py\classes.py", line 73, in
>   printEmployeeNames
>       Supervisor.printName(worker)   File "C:\Python\PythonLab\PythonLab.py\classes.py", line 56, in printName
>       print(str(self.name) + "'" + str(self.department)) AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'name'`

```
class Employee:

    def __init__(self, fullname, datestart, monthstart, yearstart):
        self.fullname = fullname
        self.datestart = datestart
        self.monthstart = monthstart
        self.yearstart = yearstart

    def getService(self):
        from datetime import date
        current_date = date.today()
        date1 = date(self.yearstart, self.monthstart, 1)
        date_now = date(current_date.year, current_date.month, 1)
        serviceTime = date_now - date1
        day_format = serviceTime.days

        years = int((day_format/365))
        months = int(((day_format % 365)/30))

        if day_format < 0:
            return('Still In Service')
        if day_format == 1:
            return("Last Service Time was Yesterday")
        if day_format < 365:
            return("Last Service Time was " + str(months) + " months ago.")
        if day_format > 365:
            return('Last Service Time was ' + str(years) + "-" + str(months) + " ago.")

    def printName(self):
        print(self.fullname)

    def setName(self, name):
        self.fullname = name


class Supervisor(Employee):

    def __init__(self, name, datestart, department):
        Employee.__init__(self, name, int(datestart[0:2]), int(datestart[2:4]), int(datestart[5:8]))
        self.employees = {}
        self.contact_info = {}
        self.department = department
        self.name = Employee.__name__



    def getName(self):
        return self.fullname

    def printName(self):
        print(str(self.name) + "'" + str(self.department))

    def setName(self, name, department):
        self.name = name
        self.department = department

    def addEmployee(self, Employee):
        self.employees[str(Supervisor.getName(self))] = Employee

    def isManager(self):
        if self.employees:
            return True
        else:
            return False

    def printEmployeeNames(self):
        for worker in self.employees:
            Supervisor.printName(worker)

    def removeEmployee(self, employeename):
        for worker in self.employees:
            if employeename in self.employees:
                del self.employees[employeename]

    def getContactInfo(self):
        return self.employees

    def setContactInfo(self, phone, fax, email):
        self.contact_info["phone"] = phone
        self.contact_info["fax"] = fax
        self.contact_info["email"] = email


    def getPhone(self):
        return self.contact_info["phone"]

    def getFax(self):
        return self.contact_info["fax"]

    def getEmail(self):
        return self.contact_info["email"]
```

Answer (score 1):

`self.employees` is a `dict`. Iterating it means iterating its keys. Thus, in this code

```
for worker in self.employees:
    Supervisor.printName(worker)
```

`worker` is a string. Change it to:

```
for worker in self.employees:
    Supervisor.printName(self.employees[worker])
```

Or, even more to the point:

```
for name, worker in self.employees.items():  # iterates key-value pairs
    Supervisor.printName(worker)
```

Comment: Okay, this helps. I did not think that through about the fact that it would be iterating through only the keys.

Comment: To follow up on this, I'm also getting a problem in the PrintName function. It is telling me that Employee object has no name attribute, but it does.